# Insert accented letters in passwords

Tags: keyboard, security, password, internationalization

This should be easy, but I cannot solve it by myself.

How can I insert **accented letters in passwords**?

When I go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Change Password...` and in the password field for instance I **hold the letter** `u`, it won't show the list of possible accented letters, it just repeats the `u`.

If I use `Alt+u` to get the placeholder for `ü` (so that I can type `u` to get it with the umlaut), it won't show the "insert a letter now" yellow placeholder, instead I get a beep. The same goes for `Alt+i`, `Alt+n`, `Alt+e`, only beeps and no possibility to enter an accented letter.

Moreover, if I enable the "*Show emoji and symbols*" as in the picture below, I am able to insert symbols **in the hint**, but in the password it is **completely prohibited**.

The same goes with "*Show keyboard viewer*" and try to insert with `Alt+e|u|i|n` to be able to finally enter `euin` to get the symbols éüîñ, I get a beep. The only accent that *sort of works* is the backtick `Alt+backtick`, but **it inserts the backtick itself** without prompting for the letter to be accented.

[image: Emoji and symbols palette]

Input source: US English
OS X version: El Capitan 10.11.3 (15D21)

Is there a way?

PS. By the way, when changing passwords, can I tell my Mac to **stop** asking this? "*Would you like to change the password for “username”, or begin using your iCloud password to log in and unlock this Mac?*"

Comment: Please remove your P.S. and add a second question. StackExchange works best if you ask one question per question...!

Comment: My input source is US English.

Comment: I am using El Capitan, version 10.11.3 (15D21). Unfortunately I don't have an older version to test...

Comment: Updated answer. Entering Alt+e|u|i|n|` is not sufficient to enter an accented character!

Comment: Yes, I know, I am sorry I didn't explain it clearly. I hope now it's clear that I want to enter `ü`, using `Alt+u` and then `u`. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: You won't get the yellow/orange dead key sign entering a key in password fields. Instead you get a beep. **But** after entering a proper letter afterwards you will get the accented character finally. Try it with a second user.

Comment: Note that due to possible differing encodings, using characters beyond the ASCII range (and that includes all letters with modifiers/diacritics, and a lot of special characters) may lead to issues when logging in through other means than your Mac's login prompt, including network shares, screen sharing, etc. Use at your own risk!

Comment: Might it be that this is why OSX inhibits those? It's for me unorthodox, but I can understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not a fully security bullet proof solution but definitely the simplest and quickest one.

1. Open any location where you can type in normal text
2. Type your password including the special characters
3. Select password, Cmd-C for copy
4. Go to the password dialog, Cmd-V for paste

If you want to do this in the login window, you could do the same however there are few extra steps to be taken:

1. System Preferences / Users & Groups / Login Options
2. Display login window as: Name and password
3. Log out

Now you have 2 textboxes; one for the login name, one for the password.  You can now use the same trick as the one I described above.  Small issue though; the system doesn't show the clickable accent-options assist box though.  They do work however.  (for example try pressing 'e' for 2 seconds, then press '2' and the é should show up in the textbox)

Comment: But I couldn't log into my computer with this hack, I think.

Comment: Answer edited with a solution for that.  I do admit it isn't a quick & simple method anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Entering a password with a diacritic works as expected. You have to use the proper keys though:

To enter an umlaut you have to use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
To enter an accent grave you have to use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>
To enter an accent acute you have to use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
To enter an accent circumflex you have to use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
To enter a tilde you have to use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

The above are all dead keys and have to be followed by a second key. If you enter <kbd>space</kbd> the diacritic itself is the "entered sign". Entering a dead key in a password field you neither get the typical yellow/orange dead key indicator nor a bullet - you get a beep only!

The back tick itself is no accent (dead key) but simply a back tick.

E.g. to enter an **ü** using an US English input source and an Apple keyboard with a (physical) US English layout you first have to hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and then <kbd>U</kbd> again.

In my virtual machine I get an alert sound but no bullet after entering the first key combination (the dead key `¨`) and then after entering the second (single) **U** a new bullet. The resulting letter is the (lower caps) **ü**.

---

BTW the `¨` is no accent. Like accents it's a diacritic though.

Comment: Why do you consider the ¨ umlaut to not be an "accent"?

Comment: @TomGewecke In linguistics only some diacritics are considered accents: `´ ˆ. They mark either a special syllable or vowel length, pitch or amplitude. The umlaut marks a completely different vowel.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Apple is sloppy I guess, considering all diacritics to be accents.

Comment: @TomGewecke The colloquial use or the meaning of "accents" is probably different than the scientific. But at least in the German-speaking world nobody would call the two dots "accents". Accents here are always straight or angular but they aren't dots or double-dots. The truth is: I don't even know the name (except Umlautzeichen) of the two dots in German. The diacritic ¨ itself is called trema or diæresis.

Comment: Apple uses sloppy German too it seems:  https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201586

Comment: @TomGewecke Maybe 2 % of the Hermans know what a diacritic is and less than 0.5 % heard of trema/diæresis. One have to be generous even with Apple ;-)

Comment: When inserting a umlaut with `Alt+u` **in the password**, I get a beep and no bullet, with the accent `Alt+backtick` the backtick gets a bullet ignoring the accent wish, with `Alt+e` I get a beep and no bullet, with `Alt+i` again a beep and no bullet. So is it **impossible** to get an accent/umlaut in a password?